# Line by Line balance in oracle

Tags: oracle

Please see code below and results and expected results

```
           SELECT DISTINCT VW_PM_INV_BAL.invoice_no,
           VW_PM_INV_BAL.quote_section_id ,
           paymatic_debtors_info.type,
           cl$invoices.total INVOICED_AMT,
           paymatic_debtors_info.amount PAID_CR_REV
           FROM paymatic_debtors_info
           left outer JOIN cl$invoices
           ON cl$invoices.invoice_no = paymatic_debtors_info.ref
           left outer  JOIN VW_PM_INV_BAL
           ON VW_PM_INV_BAL.invoice_no          = cl$invoices.invoice_no
           WHERE VW_PM_INV_BAL.quote_section_id = '1000065052'
           ORDER BY 1,  2 DESC;
```

Results

```
Invoice_no  Quote_section_id    Type    Invoiced    Paid_CR_REV
729001     1000065052           Inv      70680       70680
729001     1000065052           Pmt      70680      -70680
732331     1000065052           Inv      21556.26    21556.26
732331     1000065052           Pmt      21556.26   -21556.26
751231     1000065052           Inv      21556.374   21556.37
751231     1000065052           Pmt      21556.374  -21556.37
753107     1000065052           Inv      21556.374   21556.37
753107     1000065052           Pmt      21556.374  -21556.37
753107     1000065052           Rev      21556.374   21556.37
```

Expected

```
Invoice_no  Quote_section_id    Type    Invoiced    Paid_CR_REV  Balance
729001     1000065052           Inv      70680       
729001     1000065052           Pmt                  -70680       0
732331     1000065052           Inv      21556.26    
732331     1000065052           Pmt                  -21556.26    0
751231     1000065052           Inv      21556.374  
751231     1000065052           Pmt                  -21556.37    0
753107     1000065052           Inv      21556.374   
753107     1000065052           Pmt                  -21556.37    0
753107     1000065052           Rev      21556.374                21556.374
```

Answer (score 0):

You have selected only five columns from the query. there is no balance column in selected list. Can you check your query again?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT VW_PM_INV_BAL.invoice_no , -- 1st column
           VW_PM_INV_BAL.quote_section_id , -- 2nd column
           paymatic_debtors_info.type,      -- 3rd column
           cl$invoices.total INVOICED_AMT,  -- 4th column
           paymatic_debtors_info.amount PAID_CR_REV -- 5th coulmn
           FROM paymatic_debtors_info
```

see there in no Balance column selected.